# Python Tkinter: Update entry field from another class

Tags: python-2.7, class, oop, tkinter

I have a Python Tkinter GUI class as following:

```
import Tkinter as tk 

class AppClient(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        error_class = ErrorClass()
        self.val_error_code = error_class.error_message

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        ##Frame for error message display
        error_frame = tk.Frame(self, highlightbackground="violet", highlightcolor="violet", highlightthickness=1, width=600, height = 60, bd= 0)
        error_frame.pack(padx = 10, pady = 5, anchor = 'w')

        ## error code: Label and Entry
        tk.Label(error_frame, text = 'Error message').grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'w')
        self.error_code = tk.Entry(error_frame, background = 'white', width = 27)
        self.error_code.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'w', padx = 5, pady = 5)

    def update_error_messsage(self):
        self.error_code.delete(0, 'end')
        self.error_code.insert(0, self.val_error_code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app_client = AppClient(root)
    app_client.mainloop()
```

I want to update the entry field `error_code` dynamically by using the function `update_error_message`. The problem is, error message is continuously updated from another class `ErrorClass()` and I am receiving the error message to my AppClient class by variable `error_message`.

How can I update the `error_code` entry filed whenever the value of the variable `error_message` got updated in another class (`ErrorClass()`)

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve] that includes two classes, if the problem is related to using two classes.

Comment: I think an answer I posted for another question might help you here. I give an example of how to interact with a class from another class. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701488/new-instance-of-toplevel-classes-make-overlapping-widgets/44703704#44703704).

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I updated the ErrorClass(). Hope this will help

Comment: I don't see anywhere in `ErrorClass` where you're trying to interact with the `AppClient` class.  If I put those two classes in a file and try to run them, it won't duplicate your problem. If we can't duplicate the problem, it makes it very hard for us to recommend a fix.

Comment: My ErrorClass actually contains a lot of code. I can not show them all. This is a TFTP client implementation, and in ErrorClass I am receiving error messages from the TFTP server. I want to update the error messages in the AppClient Tkinter GUI dynamically whenever I receive an error message. And these classes are in separate files. not in the same file.

Comment: We don't need to see all the code. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is that you need a reference to your instance of `AppClient` inside of `ErrorClass`, and then allow the instance of `ErrorClass` to pass the new value to the app

For example:

```
class AppClient(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        error_class = ErrorClass(self)
        ...
    def update_error_messsage(self, error_code):
        self.error_code.delete(0, 'end')
        self.error_code.insert(0, error_code)

class ErrorClass():
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def update_error(self):
        ...
        error_code = 42
        self.app.update_error_message(error_code)
```